# Proper way to get a DOM element

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have a unique situation going on. I am using Angular 2 with Ionic 2 to make a phone app. I need to get the DOM element of one of Ionic 2's components to insert some html into its `innerHTML` attribute.

How do I do this in Angular 2? I don't have access to this component at all since it is one of the components that comes with Ionic. To be more specific, it is the `toast` component and I initialize it in a Typescript function, but there is no way for me to get the DOM element that is created.

I could include JQuery and easily get the DOM element that I need for the component, but I read that including JQuery in your Angular 2 app is bad practice.

I've looked up using `ViewChild` but that only works in a component that you've made. Since this is a component that comes with Ionic 2 and I didn't create the component I can't use `ViewChild` to get its `ElementRef`.

**EDIT:** I forgot to say that when the Ionic 2 inserts the `toast` element it is inserted as a child of the body. So it's outside the component tree being made by my components and I can't use something like `ContentChild` to search descendants because its not a descendant.

So how can I get the DOM element for this component using just Angular 2?

Comment: What about `ContentChild)`? ContentChild allows to search descendants.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer See my edit above. I forgot to mention that when Ionic 2 inserts the toast element it is inserted on the body. So it is not a descendant in my tree of components.

Comment: I don't know Ionic or what the toast supports. Can you pass a component to the toast? What content can you pass to the toast to be displayed?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer you can only pass a string that is displayed by the toast. The string is not parsed as html, which is why I'm trying to get the `toast` element and use its `innerHTML` attribute to pass it an HTML string that will be parsed. I already did it using JQuery and it works, but it felt like a hack.

Comment: I see. Yes, jQuery is a hack but I doubt there is a better way in plain Angular2 (if not Ionic provides something special).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I solved my own problem. Last night I got to thinking how in Angular 2 you should never have to use JQuery or the `document` object because each component you make has access to its own DOM element as well as all its children.

The problem is that when a toast is created programmatically in Typescript, it gets inserted not in one of your own components, but into a different branch of the component tree created by Ionic. And there lies the problem, you don't have access to this separate branch (or so I thought).

Then I thought to myself, if I were designing a framework, my users would need access to this tree occasionally, or at least to the individual elements they create in it. So I went into the Ionic 2 API and looked at `toast`. There was no function defined there or anything at all that had something that would return the `ElementRef`.

I kept thinking that it has to be there. Ionic would not leave its users out in the cold like this. So I went and looked at the [source code](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/src/components/toast/toast.ts) for `toast` on github. If you click that link, you'll notice that the `Toast` class extends another class called `ViewController`. And the `ViewController` class has a public function called `pageRef()`. Well this will return the `ElementRef` of the component.

Since the `Toast` class extends `ViewController`, `Toast` has access to `pageRef()` as well. So to get the `ElementRef` of the toast all I had to do was write `toast.pageRef()`.

Then to solve my own problem, all I had to do was write the line below:

```
toast.pageRef().nativeElement.getElementsByClassName('toast-message')[0].innerHTML = message;
```

No need for JQuery or to use the `document` object.

Every element in Ionic that is created programmatically and inserted in the tree seperate to your own tree of components extends the `ViewController` class. So for alerts, popups, and many other components you can use the `pageRef()` function as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing your investigations!

Answer (score 0):

How about plain old Javascript? I know it is not the most beautiful thing but it is a solution and you don't have to import an external library (jquery). Just `declare var document` on top on your document and then: `document.getElementsByTagName("ion-toast")[0].innerHTML` if only have one, of course. Also, take care that when the toast is dismissed the element is removed from the DOM and you can no longer access to it this way.
Also, it won't be accessible in the DOM if it is not in screen.

Hope this help you.